# Desktop environments not working properly after nvidia graphic driver installation

Tags: unity, nvidia, metacity

So I tried to install the graphics drivers for my nvidia geforce gt540m on ubuntu 13.04 64 bit. I tried following the instructions here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1916961
but it didn't work right and now the only desktop environment I can boot into is gnome fallback. (I have unity and cinnamon installed as well.) in unity metacity doesn't work anymore and in cinnamon it crashes and goes to fallback. I just want to get my system back to the way that it was and I was going to follow the following instructions to install the nvidia drivers : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation

Please advise how to fix my current problem and also if I should follow the instructions provided in the link or a different set of instructions.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your machine is an Optimus technology one, using the bumblebee ppa is by far the easiest and most hassle free experience.

To undo the damage done, try:

```
sudo apt-get purge -remove nvidia*
```

to remove all nvidia related drivers.

If you installed via the .run file, re-run the .run file using teh same method as installation, this time it will ask if you want to uninstall. Do so completely.

Once done, make sure the machine is now clean of previous nvidia and other related installs.

Once done, use the install method provided in 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation
That should work...

Answer (score -2):

Try using:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove nvidia-current
```

Worked for me.

Comment: This and charlie answers are the same (relatively).